# WebView with custom CSS

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms PCL project with a WebView and am trying to attach custom css.

I tried putting my .css file for Android in the Assests folder and iOS in Resources folder both called `default.css`

My HTML is

```
<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"default.css\"></head><p></p>
```

It works on Android and uses the css. The problem is with iOS it doesn't use the css file. I am also using Xamarin Live Player for iOS debugging but I would think it supports css files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check this project on the official documentation of Xamarin forms.

It has an HTML with styles css file in the resources. Notice the default.css

```
htmlSource.Html = @"<html>
<head>
    <link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""default.css"">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
    <p>The CSS and image are loaded from local files!</p>
    <img src='XamarinLogo.png'/>
    <p><a href=""local.html"">next page</a></p>
    </body>
</html>";
```

Here is the sample and in it there is a link to the original documentation with full description.
[Working with WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithWebview/)

If that doesn't help, you will need to show us the steps you have done.